# How to insert a table within of a iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, html-table

I'd like to insert this piece of code without of an iframe:

I have the following `HTML` and `JQUERY` code and it works perfectly:

```
$('#info').append('<h3>' + 'Sectores de la comuna de Curicó' + '</h3>' +
      '<table id="sectoresTableID" class="table table-hover table-condensed" style="width:99%">' + 
          '<head>' +
            '<tr>' + 
              '<th>Número</th>' + 
              '<th>Sector</th>' +
             '</tr>' +
          '</head>' +
          '<body>' +
          '</body>' +
      '</table>');
```

But now, I want to insert this table within of an `Iframe`, I have tried to insert a table tag within of append but It doesn't work.

Comment: That is invalid code. I'm amazed it works, `<table><thead></thead><tfoot></tfoot><tbody></tbody></table>` is table format. Inside the all of those tags except `<table>`, `<tr></tr>` can have `<th></th>` and `<td></td>` Elements. `<iframe>` just needs its `src` attribute set. If that code is dynamic there is no need for an `iframe`. Of course, you will have to get rid of the unnecessary `<body>` and `<head>` tags.

Comment: If you just want to add to an existing `iframe` using jQuery, look into http://api.jquery.com/contents/ .

Answer (score 1):

If the iframe is on a different domain than your domain, this is **very probably** not possible, unless the iframe contents explicitly grant permission. If the iframe is on the same domain, you can do it like this.

```
$(document.getElementById("iframeID").contentDocument.body).append('<h3>' + 'Sectores de la comuna de Curicó' + '</h3>' +
                              '<table id="sectoresTableID" class="table table-hover table-condensed" style="width:99%">' + 
                                  '<head>' +
                                    '<tr>' + 
                                      '<th>Número</th>' + 
                                      '<th>Sector</th>' +
                                     '</tr>' +
                                  '</head>' +
                                  '<body>' +
                                  '</body>' +
                              '</table>');
```

The trick here is that you have to access the `contentDocument` before you can append anything.

Comment: `<head>` is invalid child of table

Comment: I don't disagree. I was just using his code to show how to do it